# How can I add categories and subcategories to an array?

Tags: php

I want to list Main categories and subcategories but dont know how ?

What I want to do is like this

```
Main cat 1
-subcat 1
-subcat 2
-subcat others
Main cat 2
-subcat 1
-subcat 2
-subcat others
```

I have two part codes which is printing only main categories like this,

Main cat1
Main cat2 
Main cat3

Here is the total codes Trying separate ways but cant do it.

```
$sql_select_cats_list = $db->query("SELECT category_id, items_counter, hover_title FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "categories WHERE parent_id=0 AND hidden=0 AND user_id=0 AND enable_auctions=1 ORDER BY order_id ASC, name ASC");


$cats = array();
while($row=$db->fetch_array($sql_select_cats_list)) {
    $cats[$row['category_id']] = $row;
}
$cat_ids = implode(', ', array_keys($cats));


$sql_select_subcats_list = $db->query("SELECT sub.category_id, sub.items_counter, sub.hover_title, parent.order_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "categories sub LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "categories parent ON (parent.category_id=sub.parent_id) WHERE parent.category_id IN (" . $cat_ids . ") AND sub.hidden=0 AND sub.user_id=0 AND sub.enable_auctions=1 ORDER BY parent.order_id ASC, sub.order_id ASC, sub.name ASC");


while($row=$db->fetch_array($sql_select_subcats_list)) {
    if(!isset($subs[$row['parent_id']])) {
        $subs[$row['parent_id']] = array();
    }
    $subs[$row['parent_id']][] = $row;
}


$template->set('cats_list', $cats);
$template->set('subs_list', $subs);


$category_box_content = $template->process('categories_box.tpl.php');
$template->set('category_box_content', $category_box_content);
```

I am trying to list categories and sub categories with this code:

```
 <?php
    foreach($cats as $parent_id => $cats_header_details) {
       $category_link = process_link('categories', array('category' => $category_lang[$cats_header_details['category_id']], 'parent_id' => $cats_header_details['category_id']));


       // subcategory links:
       if(isset($subs_list[$parent_id])) {
        foreach($subs_list[$parent_id]) as $sub) { 
            // do something with your subcategory


        }
       }
    ?>   




 <li><a style="font-size: 11px; font-weight: normal;" href="<?=$category_link;?>" 
                <?=((!empty($cats_header_details['hover_title'])) ? 'title="' . $cats_header_details['hover_title'] . '"' : '');?> alt="">


<img src="themes/<?=$setts['default_theme'];?>/img/arrow.gif" border="0" hspace="4"><?=$category_lang[$cats_header_details['category_id']];?>         


<?=(($setts['enable_cat_counters']) ? (($cats_header_details['items_counter']) ? '(<strong>' . $cats_header_details['items_counter'] . '</strong>)' : '') : '');?></a>   </li>   <? 
            } 
            ?>
```

I get this Warning: Think foreach is returning empty ! cant find the way how to solve it.

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\AppServ\www\site\themes\temamiz\templates\categories_box.tpl.php on line 14
```

And print Main categories on the page with the code below.

```
<?=$category_box_content;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically change your pre-template code to first get all category_ids from your categories. Then get a list of subcats which matches that list.

Now process the subs, ordering them to easily be found by their parent id (2nd loop).

Then instead of passing an sql resource to your template (bad form), you hand out the 2 arrays (cats and subcats).

In your template, you then loop through the categories, then within that loop, you have a 2nd loop which loops only over the subcats for that specific category (if any).

In code, like this:

```
$sql_cats_list = $db->query("SELECT category_id, items_counter, hover_title FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "categories WHERE parent_id=0 AND hidden=0 AND user_id=0 AND enable_auctions=1 ORDER BY order_id ASC, name ASC");
$cats = array();
while($row=$db->fetch_array($sql_cats_list)) {
    $cats[$row['category_id']] = $row;
}
$cat_ids = implode(', ', array_keys($cats));
$sql_subcats_list = $db->query("SELECT sub.category_id, sub.items_counter, sub.hover_title, parent.order_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "categories sub LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "categories parent ON (parent.category_id=sub.parent_id) WHERE parent.category_id IN (" . $cat_ids . ") AND sub.hidden=0 AND sub.user_id=0 AND sub.enable_auctions=1 ORDER BY parent.order_id ASC, sub.order_id ASC, name ASC");
while($row=$db->fetch_array($sql_subcats_list)) {
    if(!isset($subs[$row['parent_id']])) {
        $subs[$row['parent_id']] = array();
    }
    $subs[$row['parent_id']][] = $row;
}

$template->set('cats_list', $cats);
$template->set('subs_list', $subs);

$category_box_content = $template->process('categories_box.tpl.php');
$template->set('category_box_content', $category_box_content);
```

I assume this was your categories_box.tpl.php file (?)

```
 <?php
foreach($cats as $parent_id => $cats_header_details) {
$category_link = process_link('categories', array('category' => $category_lang[$cats_header_details['category_id']], 'parent_id' => $cats_header_details['category_id'])); 
// subcategory links:
   if(isset($subs_list[$parent_id])) {
    foreach($subs_list[$parent_id] as $sub) {
    // do something with your subcategory
    }
   }
?>
<li><a style="font-size: 11px; font-weight: normal;" href="<?=$category_link;?>"
<?=((!empty($cats_header_details['hover_title'])) ? 'title="' . $cats_header_details['hover_title'] . '"' : '');?> alt=""><img src="themes/<?=$setts['default_theme'];?>/img/arrow.gif" border="0" hspace="4"><?=$category_lang[$cats_header_details['category_id']];?> <?=(($setts['enable_cat_counters']) ? (($cats_header_details['items_counter']) ? '(<strong>' . $cats_header_details['items_counter'] . '</strong>)' : '') : '');?></a>   </li>   <? 
} 
?>
```

And print Main categories on the page with the code below.

```
<?=$category_box_content;?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tularis,

Now I have another Error;  `Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\AppServ\www\site\themes\temamiz\templates\categories_box.tpl.php on line 14`